On the relative authority of biblical and rabbinic law
A principle in Judaism is that perceived uncertainties in biblical laws must be resolved with stringency, whereas perceived uncertainties in rabbinic laws may be resolved with leniency.
But rabbinic laws are part of the Oral Law, which God gave to Moses at the same time as the Written Law, the Torah.  Both have equal authority.  How was the contradiction with the above principle resolved?

"But rabbinic laws are part of the Oral Law, which God gave to Moses at the same time as the Written Law" How do you know that?

https://www.hamichlol.org.il/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%90#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7_%D7%93%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F

This seems like a mistake. "Rabbinic law" refers to enactments of the rabbis, not given by God.

The rule that "perceived uncertainties in biblical laws must be resolved with stringency" is itself, according to some authorities, of rabbinic origin.

There is much dispute among the sources regarding what Moshe received on Har Sinai. See for example the sources cited by Rabbi Anthony Manning at
https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Torah-MiSinai-1-What-Did-Moshe-Receive-at-Sinai-Part-1.pdf and his series of shiurim at https://rabbimanning.com/online-courses/development-of-halacha/torah-misinai/    Torah MiSinai (20 parts)
A detailed analysis of the origins and development of the halachic system, from Mount Sinai to the present day. This course charts the historical and philosophical evolution of the Oral Law in 20 sessions.
